# Deep linking into Authorized.net mobile app

Tags: android, ios, sdk, deep-linking, authorize.net

Authorized.net has an app for Android ans iOS to use the Bluetooth EMV reader
[Android source code - Github](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/inperson-sdk-android/)
[iOS source code - Github](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/inperson-sdk-ios)
I've searched their documentation and I coudn't find anything about deep linking,
I have a web-based POS for mobile devices and I want them to be able to send a payment request to the app using deep linking,
Does anyone know if that option exists and if not, 
Am I allowed to modify the code and add that option manually.

Comment: If you figure out how to do this, you shouldn't modify it in your code. You'll lose it if you ever update the SDK. Good practice would be to fork the SDK, make your changes, then make a pull request so it can be incorporated back into the SDK so others will benefit from this functionality.

Comment: Please add more information. The links that you added are git hub links for Authorized.net SDK. Are you using the SDK in your app? If so, deep linking has to be done at the app level. From the app, you can invoke the necessary functionality of the SDK.

Comment: @JohnConde Looks like I'll have to do it myself, when it's done I'll update the SDK.

Comment: @HariharanAyyasamy Yes, I'm using the SDK but I needed it just to make a charge from my web-based POS and the option to deep link into the Authorized.net app with the charge amount doesn't not exist.